# Changing jQuery dialog title in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, dialog

I have the following the code to **load a dynamic page inside a jQuery `dialog` and place the contents of the `<title>` element of that page in the title bar of the dialog**. It works on versions 9–11 of Internet Explorer (and the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera, haven’t tried the earlier ones yet), but **in IE 8 the title bar is empty**. Any remedy?

**UPDATE:** See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/5WfcY/

```
<script>
$(".opencategory").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#category").load("category.php", {
        categoryid: $(this).data("categoryid")
    }, function() {
        $("#category").dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("title").text());
        $("#category").dialog("open");
    });
});

$("#category").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-categoryid="1" class="opencategory">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-categoryid="2" class="opencategory">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-categoryid="3" class="opencategory">Category 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-categoryid="4" class="opencategory">Category 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-categoryid="5" class="opencategory">Category 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="category"></div>
```

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Maybe use `$("title")` instead of `$(this).find("title")`.

Comment: @Bhavik Updated with fiddle. Had to modify the code a bit to make the `load()` part work.

Comment: @Barmar $("title").text() seems to load BOTH the title of the main document AND the title of the dynamic page.

Comment: Erm, looks like JSFiddle doesn’t work in IE8. So that’s that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that there's another `<title>` element being added by the AJAX.

Comment: I think the problem is that `<title>` tags are not allowed in the body, only the head, so IE8 is ignoring the titles you're trying to load.

Comment: @Barmar So I guess IE8 is actually doing it right by not allowing it. :) I wonder if there’s any other way to add the title on the fly, grabbing it from dynamic page called by AJAX?

Comment: Maybe I could save the title in a hidden input field in the dynamic page? Let’s see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I can confirm that saving the title as the value of a hidden input field in the AJAX-called page worked.

So in category.php I put:

```
<input type="hidden" id="title" value="Dynamic title" />
```

And in the jQuery I fetch that with:

```
$("#category").dialog("option", "title", $("#title").val());
```

Comment: I suppose you can use some other element, too, as long as you hide it somehow. Hide it, if you don’t want it displayed in the dialog content area as well, of course.